# GAE plugin or GAE appcfg.cmd are not working with --enable_jar_splitting parameter

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this error message:

> Preparing to deploy:  Created staging directory at:
>   'C:\Users\leet\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4768292050846213939.tmp'
>     Scanning for jsp files.     Compiling jsp files.    Scanning files on
>   local disk. java.io.IOException: Jar
>   C:\Users\leet\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4768292050846213939.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar
>   is too large. Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.

I issued the command like this, but it does not work with --enable_jar_splitting.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1100m -cp
>   "%~dp0..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar"
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg --enable_jar_splitting -e
>   user@domain.com update "C:\myfolder\myproject\war"

Any comment?

Comment: I have [reported this issue on the GAE bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9387). Please star.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java App Engine 1.7.7.1 SDK has been released to address this windows specific issue.
The Google Eclipse plugin has been updated, as well as the Google App Engine Maven artifacts and plugin (just use the 1.7.7.1 version).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by splitting the "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" file my own.

in case anyone else want to know how to do that, follow these steps
1) unzip "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" file from 7z.
2) balance them into 2 folders (each about 15mb) regardless any structure.
3) name the first folder as "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1" and second folder as "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-2".
4) make sure you have jdk installed. e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin". set it to environment so you can run the file from that bin folder.
5) IMPORTANT: you must go into that first "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1" folder and not at the parent folder of those folders.
6) launch cmd.exe and type "jar cf appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1.jar *" for the first archive.
7) do it again the same for the second archive (repeat step 5 and step 6).
8) go to \war\web-inf\libs folder, delete the existing appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar.
9) copy and paste the appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1.jar and appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-2.jar into \war\web-inf\libs folder.
10) now deploy it. it should work like charms!

EDIT:
Spelling correction.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the library error message, you have to do this:

1) open your windows explorer and locate it to your eclipse folder. e.g. ".\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\lib\user".
2) you will then see a file called "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar", rename it to "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.original". (just don't delete as you need in future)
3) copy that 2 files you created earlier - "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1.jar" and "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-2.jar" and paste into this folder.
4) switch it eclipse ide, clean the project and rebuild it. then, the error message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Using that instruction :

```
To clarify, we're going to release a minor update for 1.7.7. For the
meantime, you can re-jar the file as follows:

cd to the working directory
$ jar xf somewhere\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\lib\user\
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.**jar
$ jar cfm somewhere\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.**jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *
and replace the old jar with the newly created one.
```

from http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg67954.html
and the messages from the solutions here, I was able to make it work like this :

Open a command line and go into the bin directory of your JAVA installation where the jar.exe file is

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\"
```

Then, you need to find the file "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" somewhere on your computer. It's at 2 places (not counting the temp directories), in the \war\WEB-INF\lib folder in your eclipse project and also in the "plugins" folder of your eclipse installation. Precisely there : `\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\lib\`
You just need one of those 2 paths.

Now in the command line, just type :

```
jar xf "C:\whatever-folder-your-eclipse-is-in\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\lib\user\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar"
```

and then

```
jar cfm "C:\whatever-folder-your-eclipse-is-in\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\lib\user\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Now, if you go to that folder and check the .jar file, it should now be 11 mb instead of 30 something. Now you need to copy this one and replace the same jar in your webapp folder in \war\WEB-INF\lib\ so that both jars named "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" have a 11 mb size.

Now the error should be gone and you don't have to split anything.