# Uploading big jars to Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm added CoreNlp jar to my GAE project, I'm trying to deploy it, and I'm getting the following message:

jar is too large. Consider using --enable_jar_splitting

So I try to use the terminal to deploy it using:

sh appcfg.sh --enable_jar_splitting update war/

And I'm getting the same message.

How can deploy the app with the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [GAE plugin or GAE appcfg.cmd are not working with --enable_jar_splitting parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916462/gae-plugin-or-gae-appcfg-cmd-are-not-working-with-enable-jar-splitting-paramet)

Splitting solution in answer:

i solved the issue by splitting the "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" file my own.

> in case anyone else want to know how to do that, follow these
>   steps
>  1) unzip "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar" file from
>   7z.
>  2) balance them into 2 folders (each about 15mb)
>   regardless any structure.
>  3) name the first folder as
>   "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1" and second folder as
>   "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-2".
>  4) make sure you have jdk
>   installed. e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin". set it to
>   environment so you can run the file from that bin folder.
>  5)
>   IMPORTANT: you must go into that first "appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1"
>   folder and not at the parent folder of those folders.
>  6)
>   launch cmd.exe and type "jar cf appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1.jar *"
>   for the first archive.
>  7) do it again the same for the
>   second archive (repeat step 5 and step 6).
>  8) go to
>   \war\web-inf\libs folder, delete the existing
>   appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar.
>  9) copy and paste the
>   appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-1.jar and
>   appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7-2.jar into \war\web-inf\libs
>   folder.
>  10) now deploy it. it should work like
>   charms!
>
> EDIT: Spelling correction.